# Error using conda to update a package

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, conda

I launched on AWS EC2 an instance using ubuntu as AMI.

Then I ran a script to install the jupyter notebook and be able to access to it with the IP address and the specific port.
The code I wrote was this one :

```
sudo apt-get install git

git clone https://gist.github.com/rashmibanthia/5a1e4d7e313d6832f2ff nb

. nb/jupyter_notebook_ec2.sh 

cd;mkdir notebook;cd notebook

tmux new -s nb

jupyter notebook --certfile=~/certs/mycert.pem --keyfile ~/certs/mycert.key
```

Now I am in the notebook. Here comes my problem. When I try to import some packages and class, I get an error. For example with this line:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
```

I get this:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'GaussianProcessRegressor'

So I tried to update the scikit learn package with conda with conda update scikit-learn but I have another error:

> Fetching package metadata ...An unexpected error has occurred. Please
>   consider posting the following information to the conda GitHub issue
>   tracker at:
>
> ```
> https://github.com/conda/conda/issues
> ```

Current conda install:

```
           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.2.13
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.2.13
conda-build version : 1.18.2
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.12.1
   root environment : /home/ubuntu/anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : /home/ubuntu/anaconda3
   envs directories : /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs
      package cache : /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
```

---

```
$ /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/conda update scikit-learn

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 479, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 145, in _main
    exit_code = args.func(args, p)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 65, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'update')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 238, in install
    prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/api.py", line 24, in get_index
    index = fetch_index(channel_urls, use_cache=use_cache, unknown=unknown)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 300, in fetch_index
    repodatas = [(u, f.result()) for u, f in zip(urls, futures)]
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 300, in <listcomp>
    repodatas = [(u, f.result()) for u, f in zip(urls, futures)]
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 405, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 75, in func
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/fetch.py", line 117, in fetch_repodata
    timeout=(6.1, 60))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 835, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 330, in connect
    cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 324, in getpeercert
    'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 171, in get_subj_alt_name
    ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(
AttributeError: 'Extensions' object has no attribute 'get_extension_for_class'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kalefranz comments here 'https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3898' it might be because pyopenssl and cryptography are out of sync and this should fix it:

CONDA_SSL_VERIFY=false conda update pyopenssl

In windows to set ssl_verify the following command can be used:

conda config --set ssl_verify False

As it is said in [Problems with updating anaconda and installing new packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748838/problems-with-updating-anaconda-and-installing-new-packages)